# how to work php sql injection and use in site?

Tags: php, mysql

```
 1. how to work php sql injection and use in site ?
```

my site login process easily login any person with out username & password.plz describe how to safe login process.

example :

```
$logindetail = "select * from tablename where username = '".$_REQUEST['username']."' and password = '".$_REQUEST['password']."' ";

$sqlrun = mysql_query($logindetail);

$recordcount = mysql_num_rows($sqlrun);
```

in this login process how would sql injection be used?

Comment: can you please show us full code?

Comment: I think this would be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: check following link http://www.tricksofit.com/2013/10/difference-between-mysql-pdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change first line to:

```
$logindetail = "select * from tablename where username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['username'])."' and password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['password'])."' ";
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is still vulnerable to SQL injection (although harder).  The `mysql_real_escape_string` function has been deprecated.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are depreciated..

Comment: @SumitBijvani I agree with you, but the official documentation I have not found that this function is deprecated: http://php.net/manual/pl/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php ;)

Comment: It looks like the Polish version of the docs are out of date: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @Steve Your write. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear whether you're asking for someone to explain how to prevent SQL injection, or how someone might use SQL injection to get into your site.

To prevent SQL injection, use parameterised queries.  This has already been well explained in this question: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

If someone realised your site was vulnerable to SQL injection, they could log on to your site as any known username, by entering this into the username box

```
admin' OR 1=1 --
```

This makes the SQL that is executed on the database server:

```
"select * from tablename where username = 'admin' OR 1=1 -- and password = '' "
```

The `OR 1=1` will evaluate to true and the `--` comments out the rest of the SQL string and prevent the password check.

I'm not going to get into password hashing, as I assume this is a small example.

Answer (score 3):

use **mysqli** or **PDO** *preprared statements* to execute a query. mysql is deprecated.
Something like this:-

```
<?php
     $con = new mysqli('host','user','pass','db');
     if(!$con)
       die();
     $stmt = $con->prepare("select * from tablename where username = ? and password =?");
     $stmt->bind_param('ss',$_REQUEST['username'],$_REQUEST['password']);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->close();
```

> This can be a more safer way to stop SQL injection. Learn more from [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use prepared statements and parameterized queries.

Can achieve this by using msqli 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

quick tutorial. http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=65

example code

```
<?php


// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    $DB_NAME = 'DATABASE_NAME';
    $DB_HOST = 'DATABASE_HOST';
    $DB_USER = 'DATABASE_USER';
    $DB_PASS = 'DATABASE_PASSWORD';

    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

// A QUICK QUERY ON A FAKE USER TABLE
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `status`='bonkers'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

// GOING THROUGH THE DATA
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo stripslashes($row['username']);    
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'NO RESULTS';  
    }

// CLOSE CONNECTION
    mysqli_close($mysqli);


?>
```